# How to add a Python Environment to path given files/modules conda/anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have created a conda environment on one machine, and it works fine, even though it's not in the Miniconda3/envs folder. I have copied all files of the env and have moved them to another machine. I would like similar functionality on this machine.

I can't find it in anaconda navigator, within the environments tab. I also can't find it when I use the "conda info --envs" command. Let it be known that I can also activate the environment and use it normally with anaconda prompt, although VScode cannot find this environment no matter what I do.

I'm wondering if there's a way to specify where all conda environments are, as I would like to keep this environment is a specific place.

In summary :

-I can activate the environment, even when it's not in the Miniconda3/envs folder

-I can't see it in navigator, or using conda info --envs (unless I move it into the envs folder)

-VScode can't find the environment either, it's not in the list of python environments

Answer (score 0):

By adding the directories to the .condarc file, you can specify specific locations of environments.

> envs_dirs:

- ~/my-envs
- /opt/anaconda/envs

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html